# get value from function inside function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return

I'm really stuck with getting a value from this function, my guess is that it is because of the functions inside the functions.

(ps. I know I don't have to use quotes when I want to get a BOOL value)

Please help

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  var text = null;

  function textCheck() {
    if ($('.window-' + sc).has('input[type="text"]')) {
      $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {    
        $(this).on('click', function() {    
          if ($(this).attr('required')) {
            var placeholder = $(this).attr('original');

            if (!$(this).val() == '') {
              $(this).removeClass('is-invalid shake').addClass('is-valid').attr('placeholder', placeholder);
              text = 'true';
              //return text;    
            } else {
              $(this).addClass('is-invalid shake').attr('placeholder', placeholder + " can't be empty");
              text = 'false';
              //return text;    
            };
          };

        });
      });
    };
    return text;
  };

  var texxt = textCheck();
  console.log(texxt);
});
```

Comment: Logic is flawed. The value of `text` gets assigned after user clicks on an `<input>`. You can't access it until that occurs.

Comment: The "$(this).on('click', function() {" is getting in your way. This looks like a validation function, but you are binding an event handler which won't fire till the user clicks something. Try removing the binding and see if that helps.

Comment: even if i comment out the click function i still get 'undefined' response..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you textCheck() function ,the first $(this) stands for window
change this to your element